# the override does not change for different mouseClicked(MouseEvent e). why?

Tags: java, mouseevent, arcgis, mouseclick-event

```
JButton btnAddMarker = new JButton("AddMarker");
btnAddMarker.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 9));
btnAddMarker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         map.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                java.awt.Point screenPoint = e.getPoint();
                com.esri.core.geometry.Point mapPoint = map.toMapPoint(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y);
                SimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.BLUE, 10, Style.CIRCLE);
                Point pointGeometry = new Point(mapPoint.getX(),mapPoint.getY());
                Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(pointGeometry, simpleMarker);
                myGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(pointGraphic);


             }
         });
    }
});
btnAddMarker.setBounds(781, 56, 93, 23);
contentPane.add(btnAddMarker);


JButton btnAddgreen = new JButton("AddGreen");
btnAddgreen.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 9));
btnAddgreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         map.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                    java.awt.Point screenPoint = e.getPoint();
                    com.esri.core.geometry.Point mapPoint = map.toMapPoint(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y);
                    Point pointGeometry = new Point(mapPoint.getX(),mapPoint.getY());
                    Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(pointGeometry, symPoint);
                    myGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(pointGraphic);


             }
         });
    }
});
btnAddgreen.setBounds(781, 90, 89, 23);
contentPane.add(btnAddgreen);
```

I tried to add a blue marker and then add a green marker, but when i use the green one, the previous blue marker from the previous mouse Event is still active and i have 2 dots blue and green at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the previous graphics the try to call

```
myGraphicsLayer.removeAll()
```

before

```
myGrapicsLayer.addGraphic(...)
```